# Android Override Multiple Classes in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, overriding, adapter

The immediate answer is no, this is not possible in Java. I understand that, and this is a bit of a noob question, but i've been coding this way for some time now and i've always sort of felt it was a dirty method so i'd like to clarify what I am doing. Say for instance I have an Activity that is extending the Activity class so I can use onCreate etc etc...within that Activity, I have a SimpleCursorAdapter that populates a ListView.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
Cursor data = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
String fields[] = {"field1", "field2", "field3"};
adapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_row, data, fields, new int[] { R.id.Field1, R.id.Field2, R.id.Field2 });
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have named this CustomCursorAdapter because I am creating an entirely new class called CustomCursorAdapter that extends SimpleCursorAdapter so I can use methods such as bindView, newView etc to use buttons on my ListView objects.

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

private Context myContext;
private myActivity parentActivity;
private Button delButton;    

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    myContext = context;
    parentActivity = (myActivity) myContext;

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
    final int getId = cursor.getInt(idColumn);
    final double increment = 0.25;

    UnitsConversions convert = new UnitsConversions();

    int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
    String getName = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainName);
    name.setText(getName);

    delButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.DeleteButton);
    delButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            parentActivity.deleteItem(getId);
        }           
    });


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_item, null);
    return view;
}
```

I have scaled my code down a lot here just to use as an example so if I removed anything that makes this non working code I appologize, but non-working code isn't the purpose of my question. My question is, is this the only way to override methods unless I extend the activity itself with a SimpleCursorAdapter? It doesn't seem like a big deal, but when I have 10 different activities, all doing basically the same thing but with different ListViews and items and I have to create 10 different CustomCursorAdapter's it seems dirty and redundant. Maybe there is a way to create only 1 other activity and then pass in the items I need? It seems like it would be a lot cleaner to just use SimpleCursorAdapter instead of having to create a custom one and override the methods I need right in the Activity. If I didn't name this question properly, please feel free to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a nicer way. You can create a subclass of Activity (and declare it abstract if you like) which implements overrided versions of every method in which you share code across your 10 classes. Then for each real Activity you need, extend that subclass of Activity and just make the changes you need to each method. If a method is different in each class but shares most of its code with the other Activities, then you can call the general super.method() and then apply the specific changes.

Comment: Ok so you're saying create a new class called SubActivity (or whatever) and extend Activity, then declare another class within that same SubActivity and extend SimpleCursorAdapter and whatever else I might need. Then extend that SubActivity and I will have all my methods available from multiple classes that I can override at my discretion? Could I perhaps get an example?

Comment: Yes. For a really simple example, imagine SubActivity declares a public instance variable TextView called tv, and writes its onCreate method to call setContentView on that TextView. Then in each real Activity, in onCreate, you would just call super.onCreate() and then say tv.setText("Some String");   You would not have to declare a TextView in every sub class and repeat the setContentView line as well, only the line changing the Activity specific text would be needed.

Comment: Makes sense, but is there is no way to basically call multiple classes within that subclass and then extend the sub class in the real activity so I have access to override all the classes declared in the sub class? For each different activity I have different variables so it doesn't make much sense for me to try and reuse that part of the code. I would prefer to just be able to override the method in my activity so I can keep everything all need and tidy rather than have to have Activity1, and CustomAdapter1, Activity2, CustomAdapter2 etc.